# PDF Link Styling : Hovering over links to create an outline over them

Tags: pdf, hover, adobe, acrobat

I have a PDF showcasing furniture that I am currently editing with Adobe Acrobat DC. On the index page of the PDF, I have links of sofa models where viewers can hover there mouse over the sofa model links and click to be directed to that model in the PDF. This has been working and is pretty straightforward. My question is, is there a way within adobe acrobat to set the mouse over/mouse hover so that when a viewer hovers over a link with the mouse cursor, an outline will appear over the link or any type of visual representation that they are hovering over it. Any information or any alternative way to do this would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use links, use buttons that execute links. Buttons have a normal, over, and down,  appearance state that you can set.

Comment: Thank you so much. This has helped me greatly.